Confusion about the definition of law of a random variable vs reality
I first learned elementary probability theory without using the measure theory and then a more advanced version, but I feel quite hard to merge them together.
Suppose we begin with a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\Bbb{P})$. A random variable $X$ is a discrete random variable if it takes value in $(E, 2^E)$ where $E$ is finite or countable. The law of it is the pullback measure
$P_X(B) := \Bbb{P}(X^{
−1}(B)) , ∀B ∈ 2^E.$ and for discrete cases, one can simply write
$P_X(B) = \sum_
{x\in B}
\Bbb{P}(X = x)$, so by knowing $\Bbb{P}(X = x)$, we know $P_X(B)$ for all $B$.
In conclusion, it seems we have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\Bbb{P})$ first, but In practice, it seems we define a discrete r.v. in the opposite direction from the statements given above, for example,
The Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p ∈ [0, 1]$. This is the law of a
random variable with values in $\{0, 1\}$, such that
$P(X = 1) = p , P(X = 0) = 1 − p.$
Here we do not have any info about $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\Bbb{P})$, just saying  $P(X = 1) = p , P(X = 0) = 1 − p.$ is the law. Why is it a law? Why $P(X = 1) = 2/3 , P(X = 0) = 1/2.$ not a law? I am really confused about how to transition from the theoretical definition to the practical one?
My way trying to understand: We let $(E, 2^E)$=$(\{0,1\}, 2^{\{0,1\}})$, we define a probability measure on it satisfying
$P_X(B) = \sum_
{x\in B}
\Bbb{P}(X = x)$, and $P_X(1) = p , P_X(0) = 1 − p.$ We need to check it is indeed a probability measure (Countable additivity, $\emptyset$ has measure $0$ and $\{0,1\}$ has measure $1$? )

There are also random variables that take continuous values.

Some people (and some languages) use "law" instead of "distribution".  For example on Wikipedia, the English "Probability distribution" page is linked to the French "Loi de probabilité" page. $P(X = 1) = 2/3 , P(X = 0) = 1/2$ is not a probability distribution or law because $\frac23+\frac12 > 1$

$P(X = 1) = p , P(X = 0) = 1 − p$ does tell you something about $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\Bbb{P})$, namely that $\Omega$ can be partitioned into three disjoint subsets, each an element of $\mathcal{F}$, which if they were labelled $S_1={\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega)=1}$ and $S_0={\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)=0}$ and $S_={\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega)\not \in {0,1}}=\Omega\backslash (S_1 \cup S_0)$ would have $\Bbb{P}(S_1)=p$ and $\Bbb{P}(S_0)=1-p$ and  $\Bbb{P}(S_)=0$.

But following the fashion, we have $\Bbb{P}$ a probability measure and a random variable $X$ first, it is easy to show $P_X$ is a probability measure. But in practice, Give $P(X=1)$ seems skipping all the steps.

The problem is in general just saying $\Bbb{P}(X = a_i) = b_i$ can not guarantee $\Bbb{P}$ is a probability measure.

I think I understand your confusion. Let's clarify a few things:
The probability space is what we care about, more specifically, it's the value of certain sets under the probability measure that we want to compute.
A random variable, in a sense, relates two different probability spaces. We say $X: (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) \to (E, \mathcal{E}, Q)$ if $X$ is a measurable function on the underlying sets, and for all $B \in \mathcal{E}$,
$$
Q(S) = P(X^{-1}(B)).
$$
This is equivalent to how random variables are usually defined, as a measurable function $X: (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) \to (E, \mathcal{E}).$ We have the pushforward measure
$$
P_X(B) := P(X^{-1}(B)).
$$
Then it's easy to see that $X: (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) \to (E, \mathcal{E}, P_X)$ in the sense I defined above.
Random variables allow us to compute new probability space from previously known probability space, says, the probability space of sum of a pair of identical dice from the probability space of a die. Since random variables are so useful, and provide us universal notations, we tend to use them even when we don't need to. When we work with a single probability space, we tend to take the identity function to be the random variable, althought it's logically redundant.
You may already know this at this point, but your main concern has nothing to do with random variables at all, but rather how we define probability measures.  There are many such ways, in discrete cases, we usually define probability measures from probability mass functions, in continuous cases, there are probability density functions, cumulative distribution function.
In finite cases like your examples, the only conditions probability mass functions (which is what called 'laws' in your case), is that they are non-negative and their sum on the whole space equal one. If $p$ is one such function, we can define probability measure $P$ by
$$
P(B) = \sum_{x \in B} p(x).
$$
Only countable additivity (which reduces to finite additivity in this case anyway) is non-trivial to check. Let $\{ B_n \}$ be a collection of disjoint subsets of $B$, then
$$
\sum_{n} P(B_n) = \sum_n \sum_{x \in B_n} p(x) = \sum_{x \in \cup_n B_n} p(x) = \sum_{x \in B} p(x) = P(B).
$$

I am not sure I understand your points. Do you mean that indeed we do not care $(\Omega, F, P)$, for a Bernoulli random variable, we just define the probability measure $P'$ on $({0,1}, 2^{{0,1}})$ by stating $P'(B)=\sum p(x)$, $P'$ is a probability measure iff all $p(x)$ are non negative and has summation 1? We can also guarantee the existence of a random variable with this law.

@Andrew_Ren From the way you phrased your question, I feel that you think $(\Omega, F, P)$ is a different sort of object from $({ 0, 1 }, 2^{{0, 1}}, P')$. They aren't, both are just probability spaces. Like I said before, you don't need random variables for case like these, but if you want one, just set $(\Omega, F, P) = ({ 0, 1 }, 2^{{0, 1}}, P')$ and define the random variable to be the identity function.

I think I understand, we still have $(\Omega, F, P)$ and a random variable $X$, so we can have the push-forward measure (which is defined as the law of $X$). Saying $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable is just saying 'Wow, the push-forward measure is miraculously just has this form'. Similiarly, saying $X$ is a Normal random variable is just saying 'Wow, the push-forward measure is miraculously can be seen as the integral with repect to the Normal density'
